# Temporarily suspend Ruby Redis pipeline

Tags: ruby, redis, pipeline

Can I have a ruby redis pipelined block which pipes a bunch of redis queries but also has certain queries which should execute immediately and not as a part of the pipeline?

A very basic way I can think is by creating 2 redis instances connected to the same redis server and run one instance for the pipelined queries and the other for the immediate ones. Anything better?

Comment: What's your goal? Throttle the queries? Also pay attention of the nomenclature: "Redis Instance" it's the same as "Redis Server", you probably meant to have 2 Redis connections.

Comment: I am sorry about that I meant 2 Redis Connections. Yes I want to use results from a "get" query in another "set" query which I want to pipeline.